# Using duality argument to show that the intersection of kernels are nonzero.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$ equipped with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $k:H\times H\to K$. Now the map $\phi:H\to H^*$ defined by $x\mapsto k(x,\cdot)$ is then injective by nondegeneracy of $k$, thus surjective by dimension.

Now suppose $\Phi\subset H^*$ such that $\Phi$ does not span $H^*$, how do I deduce that there exist $h\in H. h\ne 0$ such that $\alpha(h) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$? My book says by duality and no other comment is given, but I failed to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by user68061 is correct, but just to spell out a few details:

1) The surjective map $V \to V/W$ dualizes to an injective map $(V/W)^* \to V^*$ (so nonzero functionals on $V/W$ lift to nonzero functionals on $V$)

2) Applying this to $\langle \Phi \rangle \subseteq H^*$ gives a nonzero functional $h^*$ on $V^*$, such that $h^*$ vanishes on $\Phi$.

3) The natural map to the bidual, $H^{**}$, given by $h \mapsto (\alpha \mapsto \alpha(h))$ is always injective (for vector spaces) and is an isomorphism if the dimension is finite. Thus the nonzero functional $h^*$ from (2) corresponds to a nonzero element $h \in H$, such that $\alpha(h) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to construct a functional on $V$ that is nonzero but is zero on some subspace $W \subset V$. That's easy to do in coordinates, but you can do it coordinate-free:

consider the space $V/W$. It is not zero-dimensional so it has nonzero functional on it. Now just lift this functional to the functional on $V$ (Natural projection $V \to V/W$ gives you the map $(V/W)^* \to V^*$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\dim H$, $V=\mathrm{span}\,\mathrm{\Phi}$, $e_1^*,\ldots, e_k^*$ a basis of $V$ 
which can be extended to 
$\mathcal B^*=\{e_1^*,\ldots,e_k^*,e_{k+1}^*,\ldots,e_n^*\}$, a basis of $H^*$.

Let $\mathcal B=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ a dual basis of $\mathcal B^*$, i.e., $e_i^*(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then, for any $h\in\mathrm{span}\,\{e_{k+1},\ldots,e_n\}$ and any $a\in V$ we have that $h=\sum_{j=k+1}^n h_je_j$ and $a=\sum_{i=1}^k a_ie^*_i$ and hence
$$
a(h)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=k+1}^n a_ih_j\delta_{ij}=0
$$

Comment: $V = \langle\Phi\rangle$

Comment: @mezhang: Correct.